# microk8s gpu enablement on WSL2

Tags: nvidia, microk8s

Does microk8s support gpu enablement and kubeflow on wsl2 Ubuntu 20.04? I understand and also successfully tested Tensorflow-GPU on WSL2 in a docker setting. Wondering if microk8s currently support similar setup?

Came across something related to kubeflow enablement in WSL2, but using k3s and no mention of microk8s.

Thanks